# Returning a variable name for a Rectangle created in Javafx

Tags: java, variables, javafx

Is it possible to return the name you gave to a Rectangle object when you created it? For example:

```
Rectangle f = new Rectangle();
f.getName() \\would return "f"
```

Comment: Look for Java reflection

Comment: No. `f` is a local variable in this code snippet. The name of the variable is not part of the object, and cannot be accessed at runtime. (What would you expect to get, for example, if you had two references to the same object?)

Comment: The other thing to point out here is that in your suggested code, you could - trivially - replace `f.getName()` with `"f"`. While that may seem facetious to point out, there are *no* meaningful contexts in which the same statement isn't true. Probably here you need to actually explain what it is you're really trying to do.